# Ruby: How do you pass in multiple :locals into index.erb?

Tags: ruby, erb

```
    somevariable = "hello"
    answer = {yesorno: "yes"}
    anotheranswer = {whatisit: somevariable}
    erb :index, :locals => answer, anotheranswer
```

When I try to run the server it says :

> syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>.

If I remove the `anotheranswer` from the locals, then it just passes in that one answer, and it works fine.

How do I pass in multiple `:locals`?

Answer (score 1):

They all have to be in the same hash.

```
erb :index, :locals => { whatisit: somevariable, yesorno: "yes" }
```